# Bookmarklet returning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I'm completely new at coding and I'm attempting to create a bookmarklet that will automatically click checkboxes with certain names. In this case, I'm trying to get the bookmarklet to autoclick the "A" checkbox.

I'm using this website to test out my code. http://jsfiddle.net/fjaeger/L9z9t04p/4/

What I have saved in the bookmarklet is:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.querySelector('%23check-a').click()%7D)()
```

This is what I got after putting

```
 document.getElementById('check-a').click();
```

through https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/

My code runs fine when entering into the Chrome console but when I use it as a bookmark, it comes as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
at < anonymous>:1:47
at < anonymous>:1:57
```

Comment: Note that your first code example uses `querySelector` and the second is using `getElementById`. You probably  changed it during your tests and forgot to update the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've written is correct. The problem here is the jsfiddle website. This site is running your code inside an iframe element, not on the page itself. `document` refers to the current document, but the iframe is a different `document`, and your code doesn't find the element.

You could try with

```
window.frames[0].document.getElementById('check-a').click();
```

However, you'll get an error, because that frame is on a different origin and the browser is blocking access to cross-origin resources.

Try to write a simple HTML page to test your bookmarklet.